# How to separate words characters and non word characters?

Tags: vb.net, unicode

Unicode have categories of characters. Some are alpha numeric. Some are punctuation.

What about if I want to know whether a word belongs to keyword or not

For example,

A,a,b,c, tend to belong to words. So is Ƈ,Ǝ,ǟ, so are all chinese characters.

Sentences like

```
Hello World, I "like" (to)  eat ƇƎǟ and 款开源 ©
```

Have keywords:

```
Hello
World
I
like
to
eat
ƇƎǟ
款
开
源
```

Here, , (),© are not word characters and hence should just be ignored and use.

© doesn't count as punctuation either. '©'.IsPunctuation returns false in vb.net but I want to get rid of that too.

Now I want to make a program that can split sentences into keywords. For that I need to know which characters are word characters and which one is not.

Is there a vb.net function for that?

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way round: use `IsLetter` for your test. Or better yet, use regular expressions to split your string by words:

```
Dim str = "Hello World, I ""like"" (to)  eat ƇƎǟ and 款开源 ©"
Dim wordPattern As New Regex("\p{L}+")

For Each match in wordPattern.Matches(str))
    Console.WriteLine(match)
Next
```

Here, `\p{L}` matches any word character. However, the above matches “款开源” in a *single* rather than in separate matches since there is no separator between the characters.

Comment: and how to know whether something is a letter?

Comment: @JimThio Like I said: by using `IsLetter` instead of `IsPunctuation`.

Answer (score -2):

u need to deal with "keycodes" 
like if u only want letters [a-z]
then

```
       for(c>='a' && c<='z'){
       }
```

or

```
       for(c>=97 && C<=122){
        }
```

Comment: I would to avoid that. Number of acrylics and chinese characters are too great.

Comment: The question is about Unicode, your answer isn’t. Oh, and the syntax is invalid.